# Несколько вопросов по Yii

Tags: framework, yii

Только стал знакомиться с yii, про нее вообще ничего не знаю

Скачал, запустил на локальном сервере

И сразу появилось несколько вопросов

Хочу сделать небольшую цмс-ку

Как можно сделать на yii вот такую вот структуру?

http://site.qq/

http://site.qq/admin/

т.е. отдельно админка, отдельно сам сайт

А так же можно как то реализовать возможность расширять цмс с помощью модулей?

т.е. допустим есть папка http://site.qq/modules/

В которой находятся модули, допустим для оплаты и т.д. и через админку их можно подключать к цмс-ке или отключать

т.е. это вообще просто сделать или там уже это как то сделано? или что админка что сайт там нет разделения?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на первый вопрос: Если вы смс будете писать то вам надо создать ведущий модуль, чтоб все модули унаследовались от туда и в этом модуле ведущий контроллер нужно делить на два (унаследовать два контроллера) Frontcontroller и Backcontroller и от туда будете унаследовать.

Вот на хабре написано, как сделать но это для мелких проектов http://habrahabr.ru/post/117457/ Но мне не понравился, может вы от туда чтоб нибудь извлекните

Второй вопрос: расширять можно с модулями сколько угодно

Answer (score 1):

я тоже учусь yii, начал пилить пример блога: https://github.com/ram0973/yiiblog
в папке protected создал папку backend, админка лежит там полностью, а в корне лежат 2 точки входа - index.php и backend.php. В корневом .htaccess добавлена строчка RewriteRule ^backend backend.php. (В папке backend пока мешанина, но всё работает :)). Админка и главная - это 2 разных приложения.

А ещё есть проект yupe.ru - готовая CMF, в ней можно как раз модули включать/выключать.

И ещё есть пример приложения yii2 - https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced

Ещё https://github.com/clevertech/YiiBoilerplate